# Small fraction problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is probably very easy, but I just can't figure out how this book converts
$$p + \frac{1}{p-2}$$
into
$$\frac{p-1}{(p+1)(p-2)}$$
with $p \in \mathbb{C}$:
[image: what my book show]
Thank you in advance !

Comment: your two initial expressions are not the same.  Taking $p=0$, say, the first is $-\frac 12$ and the second is $\frac 12$.

Comment: Clearly $1+\frac1{p-2}=\frac{p-1}{p-2}$ for $p \not = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, you should recognize that the way you asked the question is wrong.  It is not the book saying that $p+\frac{1}{p-2}$ is equal to $\frac{p-1}{(p+1)(p-2)}$, it is saying that $(p^2-1)\gamma(p)-p+1=1+\frac{1}{p-2}$ implies that $\gamma(p)=\frac{p-1}{(p+1)(p-2)}$.  You seem to have ignored the $(p^2-1)$ being multiplied by the $\gamma(p)$ in the first expression.

The first line reads $$(p^2-1)\gamma(p)-p+1=1+\dfrac{1}{p-2}$$

Add $p$ to both sides, and then subtract $1$ from both sides of the first line.  This will say that $$(p^2-1)\gamma(p)=p+\frac{1}{p-2}$$

Next we can divide both sides by $(p^2-1)$ to get $$\gamma(p)=\dfrac{p+\frac{1}{p-2}}{p^2-1}$$

Since we don't like fractions inside of fractions, let us try to clean it up a bit.  You see that $p$ standing by itself in the numerator?  Let us "multiply by one" in the form of $\frac{p-2}{p-2}$ so that we can later combine it with the rest of the numerator $$\gamma(p)=\dfrac{p\cdot\frac{p-2}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-2}}{p^2-1}=\dfrac{\frac{p^2-2p+1}{p-2}}{p^2-1}$$

Now, since $(a/b)/c = a/(bc)$ let us clean it up by moving the middle denominator to the bottom.

$$\gamma(p)=\dfrac{p^2-2p+1}{(p^2-1)(p-2)}$$

Finally, let us factor each expression and then cancel where we can.  Recall that $p^2-2p+1 = (p-1)^2$ and that $p^2-1 = (p+1)(p-1)$ to get

$$\gamma(p)=\dfrac{(p-1)(p-1)}{(p-1)(p+1)(p-2)} = \dfrac{(p-1)}{(p+1)(p-2)}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear for me now